# Ruby on Rails - rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I am having a lot of trouble setting this gem up. I just added the gem yesterday--first, is it truly compatible with Rails 4? (because that's what I am using)

If so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have `UserOrganizations` and `Organizations` models. UserOrganizations stores the relationships between users and orgs--so it `belongs to` orgs.

I want people to search by the organization's `:name` to add it as a relationship to their user account. In the user_organizations_controller.rb:

```
  autocomplete :organization, :name, full: true
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :user_organizations do
    get :autocomplete_organization_name, on: :collection
  end
```

Then, continuing on with the tutorial [provided here](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete), I add the following in UserOrganization's _form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :organization_name,
  autocomplete_organization_name_user_organizations_path %>
```

This then returns:

```
undefined method `organization_name' for #<UserOrganization:0x6846f48>
```

In the view, do I actually need to put in `:organization`? `:name`? If not, I am not sure what I need to be doing differently, I followed the tutorial pretty closely and it put in `:brand_name` despite that not being an actual attribute name. I have the gems jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails installed, and autocomplete-rails.js is listed with the other script files. Thanks for any help. This is, of course, after restarting the server repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Nevermind, I've decided to use the select2 gem instead. It's way easier and does exactly what I want. Not sure if I didn't understand the tutorial directions or it is compatibility issues with Rails 4, but I've found this instead.